# Redis `DUMP` command, but human readable?

Tags: database, redis, dump

I've been searching for a while and I can't seem to find any way to print values of anything in Redis in a human readable way (Maybe get, but doesn't work on lists).

This is an example. I have a list with one item:

```
"\x01\x01\xc3D`F(\x11{\"eventName\":null,\x80\x10\x03Valu\xe0\x00\x11\x06siteKey\xc0 \x01vi \x10\x03orId\xc0\x10\x06referer\xe0\x02\x0e\x03resh\xe0\x01\x1f\x06session@\x10\x1f\"sv0l5fdqk1rv26k1qeb367kr53\",\"co\x01nt \x8d\x03Titl\xe0\x00|\rtimestampBrows\xe0\x01e\x02cli *\x02Utm\xc0v \x1b\x00v@\x1e\x05{\"USER j\awww-data X\x03HOME \x11\x04/var/ \x16 \x11\aFCGI_ROL@\x16\x06RESPOND 4\x10,\"APPLICATION_ENV 4\x0clocal-env !\x0cSCRIPT_FILENA\xe0\x04V\x01/s!\x16\x1fywave-analytics/code/tracker/pub\x0clic/index.php N\x0bQUERY_STRING m\x06foo=bar \x18\x01RE \x1a\bST_METHOD \x1a\x02GET \x16\nCONTENT_TYP@\xbb\xe0\x02\x11 \x8f\x02GTH ( \x13\xa0\xa4\xc0\xa0\xe0\x03p\xc0W\x02URI +\x01/?\xe0\x01q\x04DOCUM@[\xa0\x1a\xe0\x035\xe0\x00\x1b\x03ROOT@7\xa1J\xe0\x1f\xf3@\x93\rERVER_PROTOCOL D\aHTTP/1.1 \x1c\bGATEWAY_I \xdd\x03RFAC@\xdb!\xa2\xa0\x1d\xa0:\x06SOFTWAR@\x1b\x04nginx \x1d\x024.6 =\tREMOTE_ADDA\xf8\x0410.0.\x80V\xa0\x18\x02POR@\xb4\x035691@l\xa0N\xe0\x05.\x0120 H\xa0\x19\xa0/\x008\xe0\x02\x12\xa1J\xa1\xc9\x00.\xe1\x00\xe0\x00.\xe1\x00\xf4\x00.\") B\aREDIRECT!\xd3\x03ATUS \xe6\x0120@G\x13NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZ@\xc9\x015m 4A\t\x03_HOS@\xa5\xe0\x19b`-\"\b\x00N f\"\xa8 b\tkeep-alive\xc0L\x04CACHE@$\x00T\"\xe5 !\x06no-cach\xe0\x00\x1f\x05PRAGMA\xe0\n\x18\x04ACCEP`\x87\x0bext/html,app\"\xb6\x01at#\xc4\x01/x@\x11\x01+x\xe0\a\x15\x16ml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*`\x14\x008\xc0\x93C\x98\x02_AG\"b w\x18Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; I$\x03\x01l  \x10\b OS X 10_ \x02\x030) A \x84\x1feWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geck\x0bo) Chrome/36B\x03\r985.125 Safari\xa06\xc0\x8d\x80\xe8#\xe5\x02COD\x83|\x10gzip,deflate,sdch\xe0\x06*\x04LANGU \xbf \xbd\aes-ES,es\x80\xe0\x02,en`\b\xe0\x00[\x04COOKI@'\tPHPSESSID=\xe4\x14\xf9 &\x04_SELF Y\xe3\x04v\xc3\xac\x05TIME_F\"6!9\x0e1406541276.9255\xe0\x05$\xe0\x03\x1e\a},\"_erro%\x99\x02{\"p!\x96E\x81@\t\x00r%\xee\x06ters\":[e\xf3@\x04\x00]%\xf9\x80+\x0b\"No url for @5\x03\"}}}\x06\x00 \xb9\xfc\xaf\x19p)\x91"
```

Theres no possible way I can read this without spending 5 minutes figuring out what is what.

Does anybody know how to do this? Is there any third party tool I may use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you directly manipulate a Redis RDB file you can use [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) that provides a convenient way to [convert dumps to JSON](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools#converting-dump-files-to-json):

```
$ rdb --command json --key "scm" dump.rdb
[{"scm":["git","hg","svn"]}]
```

This tool also provides a `--type=TYPES` option to filter out by type if needed.

*Of course if you interact with your Redis server simply use... a client, e.g with `redis-cli`:*

```
$ redis-cli LRANGE scm 0 -1
1) "git"
2) "hg"
3) "svn"
```

Comment: Thanks. Its not really what I was hoping to get, but LRANGE prints as JSON on redis-cli, so that will work for now.

Comment: You mean as CSV right? e.g `redis-cli --csv LRANGE scm 0 -1`

Comment: `> LRANGE foo 0 0`
`1) "{\"eventName\":null,\"eventValue\":null,\"siteKey\":null,\"visitorId\":null,\"referer\":null,\"refreshId\":null,\"sessionId\": ...`

From inside the cli